# Unable to deploy the smart contract using solc compiler in mac

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am trying to deploy the Lottery contract using solc compiler of verison 0.4.17 but it's showing me nothing. But the same contract is working good in the remix ide. I providing you the the Solidiy code and also the dependencies that I have used to deploy this to the rinkeby network using infura network.

Lottery.sol(This is the smart contract file)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    function Lottery() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(block.difficulty, now, players));
    }

    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(this.balance);
        players = new address[](0);
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns (address[]) {
        return players;
    }
}
```

The following is the compile script

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Lottery.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, 'utf8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Lottery'];
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Lottery.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, 'utf8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Lottery'];
```

I want to deploy the above script from the local device(I am using mac) using solc compiler. I have to deploy the code using the following js script.

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  'joy nuclear cause beauty strike quick priority upset hello strategy manual shadow',
  'rinkeby.infura.io/v3/979787f2e36741368aee9a3d1b73b438'
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

  const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({ data: bytecode })
    .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

  console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

In order to have you the general idea of the dependencies that I have used I am also providing you the package.json file here below

```
{
  "name": "set",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.4.3",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "solc": "^0.4.17",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.9",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you could be able to compile and deploy the script successfully. In my case when I try to deploy it this doesn't provide me any output. Waiting for your solutions

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me in windows..Assuming compilation is successful and you are able to console log at all steps(contract deployed to)in deploy script, Try '0x' parameter in data: '0x' + bytecode.

Comment: Did not get you can you please be little bit clear

Comment: Hi..try prefixing bytecode with 0x if your bytecode doesnt have start with 0x..

Comment: Yes, mate tried this too. I took the bytecode and added 0x to it but I am facing the same issue.